# Flutter HTTP post request sending list of objects

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, flutter-http

I have successfully got a 200 response code from the server but my API returns response code of 0. When I try to send a request in the postman it response to 1. Maybe I do have something missing in my JSON to send in the body. I'm new to flutter and I would like to send a post HTTP request with a body of list of objects like below: I really appreciate any help.

```
    [
        {
            "product_id": 14,
            "quantity": 3,
            "payment": "COD"
        },
        {
            "product_id": 3,
            "quantity": 2,
            "payment": "COD"
        }
    ]
```

This is my function for HTTP post:

```
Future<dynamic> checkItem({Map headers, body, encoding}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
          '${_url}transactions/check',
          headers: headers,
          body: body,
          encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String data = response.body;
        return jsonDecode(data);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

This is how I call the function which I pass my JSON:

```
 List<String> chckList = checkoutList.map((e) => json.encode(e.toJson())).toList();
 String strBody = json.encode(chckList);
 final res = await interface.checkOutItem(body: strBody);
```

This is my toJson in my Model object:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['product_id'] = this.product_id;
    data['quantity'] = this.quantity;
    data['payment'] = this.payment;
    return data;
  }
```

Comment: Where you get the `response code`  0

Comment: From the api response.

Comment: what is the type of the body? I mean what do you need to pass for the request body?

Comment: array of objecs like the above json.

Comment: what are you getting back as response? I mean what should come if it works perfectly.

Comment: a response code of 1, and the message field in json format

Comment: I already solve the issue by changing the api request body to our backend guy.

Comment: It seems that you've found the solution in your post. It would be nice if you could share it as an answer to the community.

Answer (score 0):

The request in your code seems to all line in place. The issue likely lies on the API you're using that's unable to handle to handle the payload that you're sending.